# `no basic auth credentials` Github to AWS ECR deployment on git events

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr, aws-ecr

I have done setup of Flux for k8s deployment to AWS EKS, for it I have configured Github and k8S with the following:

https://www.weave.works/blog/gitops-with-github-actions-eks

but getting `no basic auth credentials`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to login into the ECR Repo using the below command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password \
        --region <region> \
    | docker login \
        --username AWS \
        --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

ECR Repository URL : <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com

Example :

```
sh "aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-1 | 
     docker login 
     --username AWS 
     --password-stdin 09xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

This command retrieves and displays an authentication token using the GetAuthorizationToken API that you can use to authenticate to an Amazon ECR registry. ~ (Quoted from Amazon Docs)

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html